# API Exporting Issue

Tags: python, api, maya

I need someone's expertise on this exporting problem of mine.

How it works: Select a camera (animated or not is optional) >> File >> Export Selection >> File Type : .chan (need to load this script as a plugin)

Here's where the problem starts. It is able to create a .text file, however, it is not 'exporting' or writing out the contents into the text file and the file size is of zero bytes.

I am making use of the current API that it has been coded, modifying the code to add in some maya cmds

Can someone kindly help me out?

```
import math, sys, string, os

import maya.OpenMaya as OpenMaya
import maya.OpenMayaMPx as OpenMayaMPx
import maya.OpenMayaAnim as OpenMayaAnim

import maya.cmds as cmds
import maya.mel as mel

kPluginTranslatorTypeName = "chan Export/Import"
kVersionNumber = "0.5a"

camSel = []
win_name = "chan_window"

class CustomNodeTranslator(OpenMayaMPx.MPxFileTranslator):   
    def __init__(self):
        OpenMayaMPx.MPxFileTranslator.__init__(self)       
    def haveWriteMethod(self):
        return True
    def haveReadMethod(self):
        return True
    def filter(self):
        return " .chan"
    def defaultExtension(self):
        return "chan"
    def writer( self, fileObject, optionString, accessMode ):
        try:

            fullName = fileObject.fullName()
            fileHandle = open(fullName,"w")

            selectList = OpenMaya.MSelectionList()

            OpenMaya.MGlobal.getActiveSelectionList(selectList)
            node = OpenMaya.MObject()
            depFn = OpenMaya.MFnDependencyNode()
            path = OpenMaya.MDagPath()
            iterator = OpenMaya.MItSelectionList(selectList)

            animationTime = OpenMayaAnim.MAnimControl()

            maxTime = int(animationTime.maxTime().value())
            minTime = int(animationTime.minTime().value())

            while (iterator.isDone() == 0):

                iterator.getDependNode(node)

                depFn.setObject(node)

                iterator.getDagPath(path, node)

                cameraObject = OpenMaya.MFnCamera(path)

                transform = OpenMaya.MFnTransform(path)

                chanMe = fileExporter(transform, minTime, maxTime, cameraObject)

                for all in chanMe():
                    fileHandle.write(all)

                iterator.next()

            fileHandle.close()

        except:
            sys.stderr.write( "Failed to write file information\n")
            raise

    def processLine( self, lineStr ):

        self.importTheChan.writeFrameData(lineStr)


class fileExporter():
    """ module for exporting chan files from application. arguments: object, startFrame, endFrame """

    def __init__(self, transform, startAnimation, endAnimation, cameraObj):
        self.fileExport = []
        self.transform = transform
        self.cameraObj = cameraObj
        self.start = startAnimation
        self.end = endAnimation
        self.exportWin()

    def exportWin(self):
        self.expWindow = cmds.window(w=150, h=100, title = "Export Selection" )
        cmds.columnLayout( adjustableColumn=True )
        form = cmds.formLayout(numberOfDivisions=100)
        cmds.radioCollection()
        self.chk1 = cmds.radioButton( label='option1', onc = self.opt1On, ofc = self.opt1Off )
        self.chk2 = cmds.radioButton( label='option2', onc = self.opt2On, ofc = self.opt2Off )
        self.okayBtn = cmds.button(label='okay!', command=self.runSel, width=150, height=35)

        cmds.formLayout(form, edit=True, attachForm=[\
        (self.chk1, 'top', 15),\
        (self.chk1, 'left', 15),\
        (self.chk2, 'top', 30),\
        (self.chk2, 'left', 15),\
        (self.okayBtn, 'top', 50),\
        (self.okayBtn, 'left', 15)])

        cmds.showWindow( self.expWindow )

    def opt1On(self,  args):
        print "User checked option1"

        startAnimation = cmds.playbackOptions(query=True, minTime=True)
        endAnimation = cmds.playbackOptions(query=True, maxTime=True)

        self.start = startAnimation
        self.end = endAnimation

    def opt1Off(self,  args):
        print "User un-checked option1"
        cmds.radioButton(self.chk2, edit = True, enable = True)
        self.start = ""
        self.end = ""

    def opt2On(self,  args):
        print "User checked option2"
        startAnimation = cmds.findKeyframe(which='first')
        endAnimation = cmds.findKeyframe(which='last')

        self.start = startAnimation
        self.end = endAnimation

        #self.start.append(int(startAnimation))
        #self.end.append(int(endAnimation))

    def opt2Off(self,  args):
        print "User un-checked option2"
        self.start = ""
        self.end = ""

    def runSel(self,  args):
        chkVal1 = cmds.radioButton(self.chk1, query=True, sl=1)
        chkVal2 = cmds.radioButton(self.chk2, query=True, sl=1)

        if chkVal1 == 1:
            print "opt1 Pressed!"      
            print self.start
            print self.end
            self.test()
            self.closeWindow()

        elif chkVal2 == 1:
            print "opt2 Pressed!"
            print self.start
            print self.end
            self.test()
            self.closeWindow()

        else:
            cmds.warning("Check an option")

    def closeWindow(self):
        cmds.deleteUI(self.expWindow, window=True)

    def test(self):
        self.actualExp(self.transform, self.start, self.end, self.cameraObj)


    def actualExp(self, transform, startAnimation, endAnimation, cameraObj):
        mayaGlobal = OpenMaya.MGlobal()
        mayaGlobal.viewFrame(OpenMaya.MTime(1))

        # Converts the float arguement into integer
        for i in range(int(startAnimation), int(endAnimation + 1)):

            focalLength = cameraObj.focalLength()

            vFilmApp = cameraObj.verticalFilmAperture()

            focalOut = 2  math.degrees(math.atan(vFilmApp   25.4/ (2  focalLength)))

            myEuler = OpenMaya.MEulerRotation()
            spc = OpenMaya.MSpace.kWorld

            trans = transform.getTranslation(spc)

            rotation = transform.getRotation(myEuler)
            rotVector = OpenMaya.MVector(myEuler.asVector())

            self.fileExport.append((str(i) + '\t' + str(trans[0]) + "\t" + str(trans[1]) + "\t" + str(trans[2]) + "\t" + str(math.degrees(rotVector[0])) + "\t" + str(math.degrees(rotVector[1])) + "\t" + str(math.degrees(rotVector[2])) + "\t" + str(focalOut) + "\n"))

            mayaGlobal.viewFrame(OpenMaya.MTime(i+1))

    def __call__(self,  args):
        return self.fileExport

    def radianToDegree(self, radians):
        outDegrees = 0.0
        outDegrees = (float(radians) / (math.pi)) 180
        return outDegrees


# creator
def translatorCreator():
    return OpenMayaMPx.asMPxPtr( CustomNodeTranslator() )

# initialize the script plug-in
def initializePlugin(mobject):
    mplugin = OpenMayaMPx.MFnPlugin(mobject)

    try:
        mplugin.registerFileTranslator(kPluginTranslatorTypeName, None, translatorCreator)
    except:
        sys.stderr.write( "Failed to register translator: %s" % kPluginTranslatorTypeName )
        raise

# uninitialize the script plug-in
def uninitializePlugin(mobject):
    mplugin = OpenMayaMPx.MFnPlugin(mobject)
    try:
        mplugin.deregisterFileTranslator( kPluginTranslatorTypeName )
    except:
        sys.stderr.write( "Failed to deregister translator: %s" % kPluginTranslatorTypeName )
        raise
```

Answer (score 1):

the `__call__` method is what's supposed to provide the contents of the file. It returns `self.fileExport`, which is an empty list that  is not getting populated.

Comment: Do you think if I re-arrange my code, by any chance will it works? I still need the UI to pop up though

Comment: You might turn the UI into a LayoutDialog and call it before you create the fileExporter, then pass the info you collect to the FileExporter at creation time.

It really looks like you could do most of this in a plain old python script rather than going through the API. Maybe that would simplify the problem.

Comment: I think I did tried out similar methods but it is not working. I think it is probably due to the way the API is coded or something, as the Exporting works when User selects object >> File >> Export Selection, which is kind of an automated process..

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is the writer method of the plugin will not wait for your exportWin UI to return the user inputs when you call

```py
chanMe = fileExporter(transform, minTime, maxTime, cameraObject)
```

By the time the user has entered the inputs, the statements that follow have already been executed:

```py
for all in chanMe():
    fileHandle.write(all)

    iterator.next()

    fileHandle.close()
```

That is why plugin-based file exporters like these have their options UI tucked away in the option box. These options will be passed prior to call to the plugin's writer().

You will need to export your options UI code (in a certain specific format) using MEL in another script file and specify the name of that file in the optionsScriptName param of the [registerFileTranslator](http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2010help/API/class_m_fn_plugin.html#eb13e594951a71b750927ac44ddd4983) call. There is a communication protocol that needs to be followed for communication between this options UI and the writer plugin itself. [RobTheBloke's awesome post](http://nccastaff.bournemouth.ac.uk/jmacey/RobTheBloke/www/research/maya/exp_plugin.htm) illustrates this process.

Ideally, the writer() method should have all the details it needs for computing and exporting without having to wait for user input.

Alternatively, if you prefer to have your own UI window and more control over the flow of things, you could write the exporter not as a plugin, but as a simple MEL/Python module. You could still use the power of the API.

Hope this helped!

Comment: I have chanced upon Rob site as you posted. I am totally not understanding it for some reasons probably cause I have no clues about the API, such as where should the file be placed etc. It is making much more lost